# Use FirstOrDefaultAsync in query when creating instance

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have the following Entity Framework query:

```
IQueryable<Unit> units = context.Units;

Product product = new Product {
  Conversions = model.Conversions.Select(y => new Conversion {
    UnitId = units
      .Where(z => z.Name == y.Unit)
      .Select(z => z.Unit.Id)
      .FirstOrDefault(),
    Value = y.Value
  }).ToList(),
  Name = model.Name
}
```

I tried to use `await` before `units.Where( ...` as:

```
Product product = new Product {
  Conversions = model.Conversions.Select(y => new Conversion {
    UnitId = await units
      .Where(z => z.Name == y.Unit)
      .Select(z => z.Unit.Id)
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(),
    Value = y.Value
  }).ToList(),
  Name = model.Name
}
```

This is not allowed as it is inside `new Conversion` ...

Shouldn't I use `await`? How can I use it in this query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach :

```
unitId = await Task.Factory.Start<int>(()=>{
  return units.Where(z => z.Name == y.Unit)
  .Select(z => z.Unit.Id)
  .FirstOrDefault();
})
```

change int to your return type.